# Ubuntu 18.04.3 is not logging in

Tags: 18.04, login

I have a Ubuntu 18.04.3. The system was running all smooth, but some days back, I closed the terminal, which had a Gedit session running on, and the system got hung, so I logged out. But after that, even though I entered the correct password, the login prompt came back in loop.

I tried several options, but the problem is still persisting.

When I run

```
sudo strace xauth list
```

it shows

```
50xauth: file /home/lol/.Xauthority   does not exist
```